# Big number calculating in Android without Exponent "E"

Tags: android, eclipse, variables, double, decimal

I am using Double data type for a variable in my Android app.

It simply takes a number and shows whatever percentage increase from that number would be:

for example 1,000,000 plus 1000 % = 1.1E7

The problem is I don't want an exponent display (the E), I want it to be in decimal.

This is a code snippet of the area which when the user clicks a Calculate button the info is displayed in an editText (Textbox)

```
enter code here

Button calc2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
calc2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()


{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {

        EditText number1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText number2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        EditText number3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);



        double editText1 = Double.parseDouble(number1.getText().toString());
        double Pluspercent = Double.parseDouble(number2.getText().toString());
        double editText3 = Double.parseDouble(number3.getText().toString());

        double Result1 = 0 ;
        double Result2 = 0;

        Result1 =  Pluspercent * 0.01 ;
        Result2 = editText1 * Result1;
        editText3 = editText1 +  Result2 ;


        number3.setText(editText3 + "");

    }
});

enter code here
```

The code works but displays with the E. Could you show me what code to use to simply get it to display the result as in decimal.  The decimal result should be 11,000,000

No need to worry about commas at the moment.

Some languages use a Decimal data type which would take care of this problem I think. Anyone know why Android do not have this?

I looked at

http://lecturesnippets.com/android-variables-data-types/

which shows a list of the data types, but Double seems to be the biggest container and uses the Exponent thing I don't want.

Thanks for any help.

Al

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a [DecimalFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) object.  You want to pass your double into the `DecimalFormat.format( ... )` method to get a `StringBuffer`, and then append the rest of the text you'd like to display to that `StringBuffer` before you pass it to your `EditText`.

You'll be particularly interested in this method:

```
public StringBuffer format (double value, StringBuffer buffer, FieldPosition position)
```

Comment: OK I should be able to use that to get it done thank you, othewise if I get stuck will post back here in a few days.